# Tensorflow: linking segmented images with data

Tags: tensorflow, labeling

I'm trying to implement a scenario where I have some 900x900 images, that have some feature I would like to segment out.  I would thus like to create a network that outputs a binary 900x900 image, specifying whether each pixels contains the said feature.

I am able to load my input 900x900 int 32 images and my label 900x900 binary images using tf.train.shuffle_batch, but the images and labels are not linked, meaning each image is not correctly attached to it's corresponding label.

I have the data input images in one folder, and the labeled images in a second folder currently.

How can link the input images with my label images?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is essentially a question about the best way to represent the labels that you have in a way ordered as per your training data.

**Representation**
A simple representation that you could use for a label can be a simple 900 x 900 mask (a numpy array) with 1's and 0's representing whether the corresponding pixel has or does not have the feature

**Order**
Assuming you have some sort of ordering or identifier in the file names that connects the input images and label images, you could load the input images and label images in the order of the file names:

```
def findpaths(path):
  print(path)
  im_paths = []
  im_dict = {}
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    # print(root, dirs, len(files))
    for name in files:
      if name.find('.png') != -1:
        im_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        im_paths.append(im_path)
        im_id = int(re.findall('\d+', name)[0])
        im_dict[im_path] = im_id
  im_paths_sorted = sorted(im_paths, key=lambda x: im_dict[x])
return im_paths_sorted, im_dict
```

The above example shows a function that loads files with the naming convention as d-1.png, d-2.png ... so on. This will allow you to create a list of file paths, in order of an identifier in the filenames. You can do this for both , input and label images, and then maintain them as a numpy array in the order of the identifier.

Hope this helps!